# Is there some conversion - like ToString() - for the QtCreator debugger

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

When I debug my own C++ classes with QTC (Creator), I only see address values in the debugger.

[image: Only address]

My classes are no `QObjects` (because they are light-weighted and just representing values). But is there a method / operator I could overload? I have tried (which does not work):

```
operator QString() const { return ..getMeMyQStringRepresentation.. ;}
```

Instead of `@0x....` I'd like to see `..getMeMyQStringRepresentation..` . Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the debugger that QtCreator actually uses is tied to a lower-level representation depending on your configuration.  However, I believe the standard install ends up using GDB.

That said, if what you want to do isn't found in the GUI, you can move to the native debugger and do something like 'print from.operator string()' if you have implemented it.  Check the 'interacting with native debuggers' [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-2.6/creator-debug-mode.html).

Another easy (but slightly annoying) way would be to create a local variable which contained the same info, that is explicitly a string (or char array), or int, or whichever representation it is that you want.

Comment: But with QObjects I usually see a meaningful representation there, e.g. with QString its string representation (e.g. "Hello World"). I can - of course - expand the details for the value @0x.. and see the correct members, but I'd like to have a representative value straight away (for convenience).